# recursive shared_ptr in struct throws error when reseting

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, smart-pointers

In my current project i have to use a pointer in a struct to reference to the same struct:
i have an 2D vector of cells which need to reference each other. one cell can be referenced by multiple other cells

```
struct cell {
//other stuff 
    std::shared_ptr<cell> previousCell;
};
```

later i want to reset this pointer to a different cell(current is a cell):

```
currentSuccessor.previousCell.reset(&current);
```

There my problem arises, when trying to execute my code i get an error in new_scalar.cpp:

```
_CRT_SECURITYCRITICAL_ATTRIBUTE
void __CRTDECL operator delete(void* const block) noexcept
{
    #ifdef _DEBUG
    _free_dbg(block, _UNKNOWN_BLOCK);
    #else
    free(block);
    #endif
}
```

The error comes up when i want to reset the shared_ptr in currentSuccessor. I am quite new to c++, shared_ptr etc. so i am not sure if i am using the shared_ptr correctly.

**solution:**

insted of setting a raw pointer i set a shared_ptr

```
std::shared_ptr<cell> pointer = std::make_shared<cell>(current);
currentSuccessor.previousCell = pointer;
```

Comment: do you have the `cell` stored by `previousCell` is some other managed context? sounds like you try to destroy an instance twice.

Comment: If you call `reset`, then it must be a new object freshly allocated and not one already owned. If you already have a `shared_ptr`, then the code should be something like `currentSuccessor.previousCell = current;` (assuming current is a `shared_ptr`).

Comment: `shared_from_this`might also be useful for you: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this/shared_from_this. **We don't really know because we don't see how `current` is declared.**

Comment: @Phil1970  i updated my question, i have an 2D vector of cells which need  to reference each other. one cell can be referenced by multiple other cells. current is just a cell out of this vector

Comment: @fdan i updated my question. i have an 2D vector of cells which need to reference each other. one cell can be referenced by multiple other cells

Comment: then Phil1970 is correct, you should assign an already existing `shared_ptr` to `previousCell`, not the raw pointer.

Comment: After your edit, you are making a copy of a cell. It might work, but I doubt this was the intent. Pointing to an existing cell and pointing to a new cell are very different things